# Not able to find Java folder in windows OS

Tags: java

I searched below Java version is present in my system, but I am not able to find the Java folder in porgram files, can anybody help me to know where this version is intsalled in my local.

I want to configure `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH` variable to include binary files.

```
C:\User1>java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_352"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Temurin)(build 1.8.0_352-b08)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Temurin)(build 25.352-b08, mixed mode)
```

Comment: It will be helpful if anybody will help me to know what is Temurin version of Open JDK Runtimeenvironment.

Comment: Try `where java`. That should give you a path.

Comment: You installed Eclipse's JDK, so look for `Eclipse Adoptium` in your `Program Files`.

Comment: If you're able to run `java -version` from anywhere in your terminal, that's already set in your `PATH`, I don't have a Windows PC to try any commands, but you could check that environment variable to check the value and get the path from there

Comment: @Frakcool I think they want to export `%JAVA_HOME%` for something like Maven. Just because the Java `bin/` directory is on the path does not mean `JAVA_HOME` is set.

Comment: Type on the prompt "echo %java%"

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl, I know, but I'm just saying they can grab that value from `%PATH%`, just another way to look for it, then they can set `%JAVA_HOME%` using that value

Comment: I have more than one version on my path, ...course the first one it always uses until it cannot find that one (implicitly) because the folder is temp renamed or dropped temporarily into another folder for safe purity sake.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows Batch (`cmd.exe`):

```
where java
```

In PowerShell:

```
(Get-Command java).Source
```

[Get-Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-command) gets information about the given executable, and `Source` is the property that tells you the path you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks.<Where Java> works for me to know the java executables.